# Kendo Grid DateTime Column Shows Incorrect Date

Tags: kendo-ui, timezone, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mobile

I have a Kendo Grid which have a datetime columns, while fetching the date from database we are getting correct date but during display Date gets changed. For ex:
DB date is 07/06/2017 but while display on website it gets changed into 06/06/2017, considering MM/DD/YYYY. Could anyone please help me on this. Our DB and Website both located in new york region.

Comment: Are you saying month and day are reversed or it changes 7/6/17 to 6/6/17?

Comment: no, While display it on website date get reduce by one. If date is 6th April then while display on website it is 5th April

Comment: What about the time? Does the time displayed is exactly like the time received from the server? If you're not displaying the time, display it as well since it could help you understand what the reason for the difference is.

Comment: We need to show only date .. for that we are using Kendo.ToString(dateVar, /''mm/dd/yyyy'/); something like that

Answer (score 4):

The Kendo UI DataSource uses JavaScript Date objects for dates. These objects are always in the client's time zone, which may lead to changes in the date. A possible option is to use UTC dates:

http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/how-to/editing/utc-time-on-both-server-and-client

---

**Edit, just copy the content of the link to here, because SO does not like the link the only answer**

Use a ViewModel with a setter and a getter that explicitly set the `DateTime` Kind to UTC.

```
private DateTime birthDate;
public DateTime BirthDate
{
    get { return this.birthDate; }
    set {
        this.birthDate = new DateTime(value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
}
```

Use the `requestEnd` event of the `DataSource` to intercept and replace the incoming Date field with the time difference.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIMVC5.Models.Person>().Name("persons")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(ev=>ev.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
    )
    // ...
)

<script>
    var onRequestEnd = function(e) {
        if (e.response.Data && e.response.Data.length) {
            var data = e.response.Data;
            if (this.group().length && e.type == "read") {
                handleGroups(data);
            } else {
                loopRecords(data);
            }
        }
    }

    function handleGroups(groups) {
        for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
            var gr = groups[i];
            offsetDateFields(gr); //handle the Key variable as well
            if (gr.HasSubgroups) {
                handleGroups(gr.Items)
            } else {
                loopRecords(gr.Items);
            }
        }
    }

    function loopRecords(persons) {
        for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
            var person = persons[i];
            offsetDateFields(person);
        }
    }

    function offsetDateFields(obj) {
        for (var name in obj) {
            var prop = obj[name];
            if (typeof (prop) === "string" && prop.indexOf("/Date(") == 0) {
                obj[name] = prop.replace(/\d+/, function (n) {
                    var offsetMiliseconds = new Date(parseInt(n)).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
                    return parseInt(n) + offsetMiliseconds
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will implement it and let you know whether it is working or not.

Comment: The solution which you have provided working very fine. Thank you again.

Comment: Good, I am glad. Please consider marking the reply as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, but we are getting one issue that this.groups() is not a function. This is when we have grids which dont have any datetime column to display.

Comment: This issue seems unrelated to the original discussion. The Grid and the DataSource do not have a groups() method. What are you trying to do? It will be best to post a separate question.

Comment: exactly, but I am asking beacuse in your provided link we are using this.groupd()